# The more degrees of freedom for a student-t distribution the flatter? If yes, why?

Tags: confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics, inference

Assume we have a student-t distribution. Is the following statement true:
"The more degrees of freedom we have the flatter the curve" ?
If yes/no why?

Comment: Which distribution does the t-distribution approach as the degrees of freedom increase?

Comment: I guess the normal distribution, based on the central limit theorem?

Comment: Nothing to do with the CLT but yes the t-distribution does approach the standard normal distribution. Is that a flat distribution?

Comment: Gaussian. Oh yes now I see this makes sense. Well, I d think it has to do with the CLT. Because if the degrees of freedom increase this means the amount of samples increase. And the CLT says: for n iid (independant and identically distributed) samples the distribution approaches the normal distribution as n increases ( or something like that in English). PS: do you know in which cases does the population variance = samplevariance?

Comment: "The more degrees of freedom the lighter the tails" is a more accurate statement.

Comment: I wonder what a "flat curve" is.  How is "flatness" measured, at which point(s) on the curve, and what does it have to do with anything of statistical interest?

Comment: or look [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=student+kurtosis+kangaroo+platypus&client=ubuntu&hs=9yF&channel=fs&biw=1192&bih=593&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiExsb17JXKAhXIkh4KHbh7AHkQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=3ZWj1pOhYPiMGM%3A)

Comment: In what sense do you mean "flatter"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand t distribution you can refine its definition.

Suppose you have a i.i.d sample of values. Following the central limit theorem, you know that the distribution of the mean follows a normal distribution. When standardized, it follows a standard normal.

$$\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1) $$

You estimate $\mu$ with sample mean and the $\sigma^2$ with sample variance. Thus everything should be fine. But it might not be. The reason could be that you have a small sample.

If you do not know the variance parameter, and you have to estimate it from a small sample you might be way off, since the CLT works on large samples.

T-distribution incorporates uncertainty regarding the estimation of variance parameter from a small sample. So, the distribution of your statistic is similar to a normal one, but it has fatter tails if your sample is small. It has fat tails because in this way you say 'I am less sure that the statistic is close to the real parameter value'. Having fatter tails, it will also have a smaller maximum.

Note however that for large samples the t distribution goes toward a normal one, so in practice the normal approximation is safer.

Comment: This is not true. It is $\sqrt{n} \frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma} $ that follows a standard normal distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected. I was too eager to go with the intuitions

Answer (score 8):

The meaning of the term "flatter curve" is vague, and may mislead.

From a statistical point of view, we could understand it to mean that excess kurtosis is reduced. The [Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution) has positive excess kurtosis. As its degrees of freedom increase, its peak increases while its tails get lighter. The combined effect, as measured by [Pearson's kurtosis coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis), is to reduce kurtosis.

But from a geometric point of view, a higher peak and lighter tails may provide to some (me included), an image of a *steeper* curve, not of a flatter one:

[image]

To my eyes, the *flatter* curve is the $d=1$ not the $d=10$ one. Lowering the degrees of freedom we "push" its peak downwards, while "lifting" its tails. The overall "feeling" is one of a shape more flat then before, in the sense that its extremes have gotten closer.

Answer (score 0):

"As the degrees of freedom increases, the area in the tails of the t-distribution decreases while the area near the center increases. (The tails consist of the extreme values of the distribution, both negative and positive.)"
Source: http://www.dummies.com/education/math/business-statistics/how-the-number-of-degrees-of-freedom-affect-the-graph-of-a-t-distribution/

Comment: The OP asks also "why". Can you say something more? We are looking for high-quality answers.